# Xml Array Deserialization to C# object without top level arrayElement

Tags: c#, xml, xml-attribute

I have the following Xml :

```
<Head>
<Name>someName</Name>
<Config>
  <Section name='One'/>  
  <Section name='Two'/>
</Config>
</Head>
```

and I would like it to map the following object structure:

```
public class Head{
   public String Name {get;set;}

   public Config Config {get;set;}       

}

public class Config
{       
    public Section[] Sections { get; set; }
}

public class Section
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="name")]
    public String Name { get; set; }

}
```

How can I do this using Attributes only (if possible?) but **without** adding a top level < Sections > above < Section > elements, and also keeping the class structure.
I have tried with XmlArrayItem, but i can't get the section elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before asking the questions, I've tried the *XmlArrayAttribute* and the *XmlArraItemAttribute* with all possible combinations of namedProperty, and the attribute to be used was simply ***XmlElement***. So I managed it like this:

just added the **[XmlElement(ElementName="Section")]** on top of the *Sections* property in the *Config* class. updated here below :

```
  public class Head{
     public String Name {get;set;}

     public Config Config {get;set;}       

  }

  public class Config
  {       
      [XmlElement(ElementName="Section")]
      public Section[] Sections { get; set; }
  }

  public class Section
  {
      [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="name")]
      public String Name { get; set; }

  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I had the same case.